# Can't send object to intent LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, object, android-intent

Sorry for my english. I spent many hours trying to send an object from one Activity to another. I need to use a `LocalBroadcastManager`. This is my example:

**FirsActivity:**

```
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mDialog,
                            new IntentFilter("list"));

        //code

            private BroadcastReceiver mDialog = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    PeopleObject people=
                            (PeopleObject) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("people");
                    popupWindow(people);
                }
            };

    public void popupWindow(PeopleObject people) {
//my object PeopleObject  is null

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), people.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
        }
```

**SecondActivity:**

```
public void startPopUp(PeopleObject object) {
//i check in debbug my object not null
        Intent intent = new Intent("list");
        intent.putExtra("people", object);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

PeopleObject  - `implements Serializable`

Answer (score 0):

hey refer this code i will get an idea how to send intent to activity-

```
private void MyaCtivity() {
Intent intent = new Intent("MyDevice");
sendLocationBroadcast(intent);
}

private void sendLocationBroadcast(Intent intent){
intent.putExtra("currentprice", currentp);
intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupit error, I need get intent like this

```
private BroadcastReceiver mDialog = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    PeopleObject people=
                            (PeopleObject) intent.getSerializableExtra("people");
                    popupWindow(people);
                }
            };
```

use `intent.getSerializableExtra("people");`, not `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("people");`